# Problems compiling Qt

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt5

Recently I downloaded Qt 5.6

I didn't knew that installing visual studio is necessary to build with Qt.

I have a poor internet connection and somehow managed to download Qt. But now is it necessary to install visual studio of 7 GiBs which is nearly impossible for me to download with my shitty kind of internet? I had searched on google and found that MinGW can be used to build with Qt. Please help me to configure it.

Comment: There is a free version of visual studio you can download. Look for community edition.

Comment: @kometen and really no good reason to download and install it. MinGW works well and it is more portable in case you use language extensions. VS tends to install a bunch of stuff you don't need and can't opt out of.

Comment: @ddriver: generally, I agree. But what about QWebEngine ?

Comment: @CapelliC - it still doesn't build with GCC? At any rate, if I want to write web applications I won't be using Qt. I always exclude the webengine from the build just like I did with the webkit before. But if for some reason you need it, and it only builds with MSVC, then you have the misfortune of needing MSVS :)

Comment: @ddriver: now I'm installing on Windows with MinGW, I'll let you know

Comment: @ddriver: WebEngine isn't available with GCC. Another nuisance is that it install a 32bits toolchain even on 64bits machines

Comment: 32bit is not a big problem unless you are doing something sizable. For 99% of the cases it is enough, and for 100% of the beginners. Hopefully, they will dedicate to 64bit GCC builds soon, meanwhile, you can easily get a 64bit toolchain from MSYS2, it even provides a 64bit Qt build, although it is a little behind, they are still on 5.1

Comment: Also "WebEngine isn't available with GCC" but only on windows. Google prefers to use the platform native toolchain for every platform, so on windows it only supports MSVC, on linux and android it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can download a pre-build version of Qt, building it yourself is not necessary or recommended for beginners:

http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.0/

The [qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.6.0.exe](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.6.0.exe) comes with MinGW 4.9.2 bundled.

Building Qt from sources can take many hours on a slow machine, and potentially fail for a number of reasons, also it has 3rd party requirements such as perl and python.